# help i new on here

Tags: updates, wine

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key

sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources

sudo apt update
```

but in after that

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

but that was happened please help i new :(

Comment: The error provided tells you the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list` has an error on line 1 of that file. The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on new installs, thus that file was added by someone on your machine with `sudo` rights. That file contains an error; we can't see what's in that file, but line 1 needs correctly (*for us to help with that line, you'd have to provide a copy of it*)

Comment: Show us the contents of `etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.